# Where Is the Casino?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

Where is the casino located and how soon is it accessible?  Do I need to pass a certain story event or need an item to gain access?

I'm about ready to enter Nevermore, but I wanted to spent some time at the casino first if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The casino is located near the beginning of **Tombstone Trail** once you have returned to the present time. This happens after you have to go there during the course of the story.